# What is the frontend language/platform of api.ai and wit.ai?

Tags: python, django, frontend, chatbot

I am trying to develop a web application like wit.ai or api.ai. I am not sure what would be the best frontend language/platform/technology for such a web applications.
In api.ai and wit.ai you create chat robots. For each robot the user define a bunch of keywords as entity. For example

`Entity: Pizza -> {Italian, French, Greek}`

Then the user define templates for the input sentences and assign the keywords of the input sentence to the corresponding entities. For example:

```
I would like to order a Italian with two topping.
```

In the sentence above, the user assign the "Italian" keyword to the "Pizza" entity. Then they just assign a output response for such a input.
The frontend should let the user performs these tasks such as highlighting a keyword, assigning to entities, showing lists of entities to the user.
Since the algorithms that I am developing are in Python, I was thinking about using Django. Do you think it is the best platform for the such a task?

I really appreciate your help.

Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While questions about technology are typically subjective and have no 'right' answer, a 'frontend' esque language will do you a lot of good here.

Something like JS, nodejs etc.. You need to be able to highlight the words on the client side and not make any request to the server yet until the user specifies what the highlighted text is. Ofcourse the service that powers your API (to persist the selected entity information) can be powered by py  or any language that makes you smile :)

All the best